# Anylogic: Is it possible to move Transporters based on travel time, rather than distance and speed?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I would like to use transporters in my model in various places (tugboats, forklifts, reach stackers, trucks, etc.). However, my model paths and animation can't be drawn to scale, detailed explanation in brackets below.
**Is there a way I can move the transporter from one node to another based on travel time (similar to what a movable resource can do), rather than speed and distance?**
The "Move By Transporter" block does not seem to allow this and I have not been able to find a solution online. Thank you for your help.

(Explanation on why I can't draw to scale: firstly, some destination locations (storage areas, etc.) are not known yet and will just be represented by a travel delay to get there, secondly, different areas of the model will be drawn to different scales, i.e. some network paths will represent a multiple kilometers and some network paths will only represent a few hundred meters, etc.)

Comment: Given you have a path-based network, why do you want to use transporters when normal resources will do what you want anyway? You can mix-and-match Material Handling and Process Modeling Library blocks in a single process.

Comment: The reason I want to use transporters is because I would like to model the interference between the transporters and record traffic density in certain areas, unless there is a way to do this with movable resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the paths to suit your animation and then simply set the speed of the transporter that gets seized to a speed so that the duration of the movement matches what you need it to be, and when the transporter gets released set the speed back to normal

[image]

Comment: setSpeed doesn't work with transporters I think you need to use setMaximumSpeed instead

Comment: Correct! Thank you @Felipe, answer updated

Comment: Thank you @Jaco-BenVosloo and Felipe. Please note the unit.setMaximumSpeed(double, unit); didn't work, I had to typecast it to work, i.e. ((Tugboat)unit).setMaximumSpeed(double, unit);

Comment: @Christelle thank you for the update - you are correct! I have fixed it. 
I have also sent this to support as TypeCasting is not needed with the Process Modelling Library  - so this is maybe something they can address

Comment: FYI - AnyLogic support responded that because the felt option is dynamic it cant be automatically casted to the selected resource type - the Unit is just of type Transporter and you can cast manually as needed